# who sets the mimetype in Downloader?

Tags: android, android-webview

In the WebView I am loading a HTML which has an anchor pointing to a location like `"http://localhost:9300/sample.pdf"`

I have also overriden the Downloader's onDowloadStart method.

When clicking the link, the onDowload method is called and the mimetype value is set to "application/pdf"

My question is how does Android know how to set the mime type?

Looking with Fiddler (I set it as a proxy on Android) there is no request done to the server when clicking the link.

Comment: When you are downloading, the server sets the MIME type.

Comment: I mentioned that the onDowloadStart method is called BEFORE the request is done on the server. Fiddler does not show the request.

Comment: Read documentation of [`DownloadListener.onDownloadStart`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/DownloadListener.html#onDownloadStart(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long)). **mimetype The mimetype of the content reported by the server**. As mentioned, look for ContentType header in the "response".

Comment: this is confusing. the whole point of DownloadListener is to handle requests which WebView cannot handle. The request is not even done yet. Again, look with Fiddler and see it for yourself.